# console app. Vs windows app

Tags: windows, service

I developed an .net application in console application which job is to submit the files to windows fax server.

It is running fine. But when I run the same application in windows service mode, It gives the wait operation timed out error message when it submit the PDF file to fax server.

But as per the requirement, I have to give this application in service mode. Can anyone please help me since I do not know the exact cause for this problem?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 1):

Does the user running the service have permissions to the folders you're moving the files from and to?

Try starting the service with your normal user account and see if that works.

**Update**

Is the "Fax software" a virtual print driver? Does it require a desktop context?
Try checking the "Allow service to interact with Desktop" check box on the service config dialog.

Comment: It has all the permission and it is working fine when fax .bmp files. The problem occurs only on faxing PDF files.

Comment: I enabled the checkbox "Allow Service to interact with Desktop". But still the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

As a small piece of advice, if you're using WCF make sure you handle the exception event in order to stop the service and start it again (from code)

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually (not via your .NET app) submit a PDF when in windows service mode?  Answering this question may at least show whether the problem lies in your app or in the configuration of the fax server.

You state that this problems occurs when faxing a PDF (via you app, in service mode) - do other file types work correctly when in service mode?  If so, then there may be some Adobe service that needs to be started.